# Supply the same filename as argument to two commands

Tags: bash, shell

On a git conflict, I can currently do:

```
git diff path/to/some/file.txt
```

... after reviewing the diff, usually I want to do:

```
git checkout --theirs path/to/some/file.txt && git add path/to/some/file.txt
```

It's painstaking to edit both paths each time, so I'd like to be able to do the following:

```
git checkout --theirs <ref> && git add path/to/some/file.txt
```

Where the `<ref>` refers to file.txt.

Any way to do this in bash?

Comment: `f='path/to/some/file.txt'; git checkout --theirs "$f" && git add "$f"`

Comment: You could use a history expansion maybe? `git checkout --theirs path/to/some/file.txt && git add !#:3` (repeat the third [zero-indexed] word `:3` from the current command line `#`)

Comment: With _yank-last-arg_: _Alt+._ (META and DOT keys) you can insert the last argument to the previous command so after running `git diff path/to/some/file.txt` you could just type `git checkout --theirs ` hit _Alt+._ then type `&& git add ` and hit _Alt+._ again.

Comment: @don_crissti - `bash`, `ksh93`, and `zsh` put the same info in `$_`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways.

You can use [history expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#History-Interaction) in (t)csh, bash or zsh. `!$` expands to the last argument of the previous command line.

```
git checkout --theirs !$ && git add !$
```

Bash, ksh and zsh have a variable [`$_`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-_005f) which stores the last argument of the last simple command executed by the shell.

```
git checkout --theirs "$_" && git add "$_"
```

Bash and zsh have a keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>ESC</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> which inserts the last argument of the previous command line.

```
git checkout --theirs Alt+. && git add Alt+.
```

You can stuff this in a function.

```
git_add_theirs () {
  if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then set -- "$_"; fi
  git checkout --theirs -- "$@" && git add -- "$@"
}
```

Or make that a standalone script and define an alias `add-theirs = git_add_theirs` in your `~/.gitconfig`.

Comment: I prefer `$_` to `!$` as the latter inserts the filename into the bash history which is not good when you want to repeat the command sequence multiple times.