# How to copy a file to a destination folder and cd to the destination folder in one command

Tags: bash, cp, cd-command

To explain my question, here is the dumb way of how I'm doing things:

```
cp fileFromMyFriend.txt ~/my_first_subfolder/my_second_subfolder/more_subfolders
cd ~/my_first_subfolder/my_second_subfolder/more_subfolders
```

What is a shortcut to doing those two lines in one? I'm not looking for a concatenation symbol such as & or ;

Rather I'm trying to avoid retyping my very long folder path.

(And I already looked through the cp man page and Googled this question with different wording before coming here)

Comment: See [Supply the same filename as argument to two commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184235/supply-the-same-filename-as-argument-to-two-commands)

Comment: if the only issue is typing the very long folder path then you can save it in a variable.

Comment: See also [How to use arguments from previous command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009412/how-to-use-arguments-from-previous-command).   I **never** remember to do any of this, and just retype, or use the mouse to copy-paste, or use a variable (and `basename` or `dirname` if required).

Comment: @steeldriver Ah I didn't realize something like that existed, thanks. I guess I was narrowing my thinking too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to just answer this question of yours: `Rather I'm trying to avoid retyping my very long folder path.`

If that's what you are trying to do, you can just do this:

```
cp fileFromMyFriend.txt ~/my_first_subfolder/my_second_subfolder/more_subfolders
cd !$
```

Comment: Marking this as the solution since this is the simplest answer for my case. I only need the last argument. I didn't know "!$" is a shortcut to using the last argument from the last command. If I had known something like that existed, I would've found this answer when searching on Google: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88642/what-does-mean/88643

Answer (score 1):

If this is for interactive use: type and run the first command normally. Then type `cd` <kbd>Space</kbd> <kbd>M-.</kbd> (you can type <kbd>M-.</kbd> either as <kbd>Esc</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd> or as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>). The keyboard shortcut <kbd>M-.</kbd> ([`yank-last-arg`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Commands-For-History.html#index-yank_002dlast_002darg-_0028M_002d_002e-or-M_002d_005f_0029)) inserts the last word of the previous command.

If this is for scripting: put the directory name in a variable. Don't forget [double quotes when you use the variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters).

```
target_dir=~/my_first_subfolder/my_second_subfolder/more_subfolders
cp fileFromMyFriend.txt "$target_dir"
cd "$target_dir"
```

If you find that you use the same sequence of commands a lot, define a [function](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Functions.html#Shell-Functions). The bash function below calls `cp` and treats the last argument as a directory to change to. If the last argument is not a directory or a symbolic link to a directory, it changes to the directory containing the last argument. This works for most ways to use `cp`, but not with the `-t` option to GNU `cp`.

```
cp_cd () {
  cp "$@"
  if [ -d "${!#}/." ]; then
    cd -- "${!#}"
  else
    cd -- "$(dirname -- "${!#}")"
  fi
}
```

Comment: This is pretty helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with the latest file you have used, you can run the following

```bsh
cd $_ # directory case
vim $_ # file case
```